# Adding boundaries to scaling/panning image viewer in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-gesture-handler

I have an image (sometimes squared, sometimes different width/height), and I want to create a square image of it. But I want the user to choose which part of the image is in the new image (not necessarily the center part). So I created a image viewer with gesture-handler and reanimated to scale and pan an image within a rectangle. I have created a working example: [expo snack](https://github.com/andresribeiro/react-native-reanimated-image-viewer/blob/main/ImageViewer.tsx)

The problem is, now you can pan the image without boundaries, so sometimes the black background is visible. I don't want this.

I have tried this for 3 days calculating the boundaries based on the translateX/Y and the scale, but I cannot find the solution. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Did you figured this out. Though i made it work on the x-axis but on y-axis, it is still overflowing and showing the black background